# A book on Banach Manifold for a Dynamicist 

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, textbook-recommendation

Hi all,

Could you give me a suggestion of suitable book about Banach Manifolds for someone that have background in functional analysis at the level of Conway's book and Do Carmo's book on Riemannian Geometry ?

To help the indication the problems I am facing in my research are for example, what are the usual conditions required to a Banach manifold to be metrizable. Is there a standard way to construct a metric on $C^r(M,M)$, where $M$ is a two-dimensional manifold ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially if your interested in dynamical systems, I highly recommend [Abraham--Marsden--Ratiu, Manifolds, tensor analysis, and applications](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=960687).

For a more Riemannian-geometric/global-analytic focus, you might want to try [Klingenberg, Riemannian Geometry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1330918), or [Lang, Differentiable Manifolds](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=431240).

There is a standard way to construct a canonical *topology* on $C^r(M,N)$ for $M$ compact, one that turns $C^r(M, N)$ into a Banach manifold.  But I don't think there is a canonical metric on $C^r(M, N)$ unless you put some additional structure on $N$.

Comment: The way Lang makes a differentiable structure on $C^0(M,N)$ is via the exponential map, in the case of Riemann manifolds, and  via sprays for more general manifolds. Is this the standard way you mentioned?

Comment: @Pietro: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

The first textbook I thought is: Palais, The Foundations of Global Non-linear Analysis, Benjamin-Cummings, 1968.

There is also: [Marsden, Applications of Global Analysis in Mathematical Physics, Publish or Perish, 1974.](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/books/Global_Analysis.html)

Finally you could look [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-06/S0273-0979-1979-14700-1/S0273-0979-1979-14700-1.pdf) at Graff's review of ``The Metric theory of Banach Manifolds'' by Ethan Atkin, for many other references.